# How to print an array value based on index number if the array is inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from numpy import array

list = [array([ 1.25e-02, -5.79e-03,  7.32e-03]), array([0.00e+00, 1.60e-08, 3.20e-08])]
```

I want to print the second index of the second array inside the list. So the output must be  `1.60e-08`.

Comment: Try `list[1][1]`?  Also, don't name a variable `list`.  `list` is a built-in and you've just overridden it.

Comment: What is `array`?

Comment: I am appending the numpy array to a list so I can analyze the data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to get specific data from a multi-dimensional list you need to remeber that lists in python are `0` indexed and that every adition square bracket helps you get data from the next dimesion.Also never name a varaible with a reserved word like list becase you overide it instead use a prefix like `my_list`

```
from numpy import array

my_list = [array([ 1.25e-02, -5.79e-03,  7.32e-03]), array([0.00e+00, 1.60e-08, 3.20e-08])]

print(my_list[1][1])
```

**Output:**

```
1.60e-08
```